# Angular 5 show data from firebase nodes

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

i need a bit of help.
I am trying to display data from specific loged in user but i have a hard time.

in html :

```
<div *ngFor="let to of UnData">
```

TS:

```
export class something {
  todo: AngularFireList<any>;
  UnData = [];
  userId: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private fire: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.fire.authState.subscribe(user =>{
      if(user) this.userId = user.uid      
    });

    if (!this.userId) return;

    this.db.list("people/${this.userId}").valueChanges().subscribe(_data => {
      this.UnData = _data;
      console.log(this.UnData);
    });
  }
```

console.log gives me nothing in return. I think i am doing something wrong in code where i am getting data from database. Please give me a bit of help :-)

Comment: You'll want to use backticks to get ES6 string templates, so ``this.db.list(`people/${this.userId}`)``.

Comment: i just found out that i can access data if i write user id plain like "sdfsrgcstcrthjyxcyxcyyfe" :this.db.list<any>(`people/user id goes here`).valueChanges().subscribe(_data => {
      this.UnData = _data;
      console.log(this.UnData);
    }); but when i use ${this.userId}, nothing happens, thou console.log(this.userId) returns me valid user id

Comment: That's because you're using a plain string syntax, and expect it to behave as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Either use backticks as shown in my first comment, or use simple string concatenation `this.db.list("people/"+this.userId)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Frank,
the first problem was backticks but i still had problems and solved and important part was ngOnInit(userId:string):

```
export class something {
  todo: AngularFireList<any>;
  unData = [];
  userId: string;
  title: string;
  desc: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private fire: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.fire.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid;
        console.log(this.userId);
      }
    });

  }
  postDatatoDB(title: string, desc: string, userId: string): void {
    this.db.list("/tasks/" + this.userId).push({ title: title, desc: desc });
    this.title = '';
    this.desc = '';
  }


  **ngOnInit(userId:string)** {

    this.db.list<any>(`/tasks/${this.userId}`).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.unData = data;
        console.log(this.unData);
      });

  }

}
```